# Twitter OAuth unable to retrieve the access token

Tags: php, authentication, twitter, oauth

I'm building a Twitter app with PHP using the TwitterOAuth library for user authentication.

I am able to redirect the user to Twitter for authentication and to receive the oauth token, oauth secret and oauth verifier, however I am not able to complete the last step of authentication where I get the access token.
I'm developing on localhost and I have set up the callback path with

http://127.0.0.1:80/TwitterApp/update.php

My app has read and write permissions.

Here's my code:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
    include "oauthConsts.php";

    use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

    // request authentication tokens
    $oauth = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    $request_token = $oauth->getRequestToken(
                     'http://127.0.0.1/TwitterApp/update.php');

    $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

    if($oauth->getLastHttpCode()==200){
        // Let's generate the URL and redirect
        $url = $oauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token']);
        header('Location: '. $url);
    } else {
        echo "something went wrong";
    }

?>
```

**update.php**

```
 <?php
        session_start();
        include "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
        include "oauthConsts.php";

        use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

        if(!empty($_GET['oauth_verifier']) && !empty($_SESSION['oauth_token'])
            && !empty($_SESSION['oauth_secret'])) {
            $oauth = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, 
                         $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_secret']);
            $access_token = $oauth->oauth("oauth/access_token", 
                          array("oauth_verifier" => $_GET['oauth_verifier']));

            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;

        }
        else {
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
    ?>
```

On execution, $access_token in update.php becomes

> '{"error":"Invalid / expired
>   Token","request":"/oauth/access_token"}' with HTTP response status
>   401 instead of returning the authentication values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out my particular issue was caused by sessions and the callback url.

I was accessing the index page through **localhost/path/to/file** , but twitter was redirecting to **127.0.0.1/path/to/file** after user authentication, meaning the session data stored on **localhost** was not accessible on **127.0.0.1**.

Using 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost to access the index page solved the problem.